# Autowiring a bean defined in XML - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I'm new to Spring (& boot) and I'm facing the following problem. I have some Beans defined in an XML file. I can retrieve these beans using `ApplicationContext.getBean()`, instead I would like to `Autowire` them, or use them in classes which do not have access to 'ApplicationContext'

A simplified version of my project:

beans.xml:

```
<bean id="PartnerDao" name="PartnerDao" class="partner.dao.PartnerDAOImpl">
   <constructor-arg index="0" value="${integration.username}"/>
   <constructor-arg index="1" value="${integration.password}"/>
</bean>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans>
    <import resource="classpath:beans.xml" />
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <cache:annotation-driven/>
    <task:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

PartnerService.java:

```
@Service
public class PartnerService {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("PartnerDao")
  PartnerDAO partnerDao;

}
```

When I build I hit the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type 'partner.dao.PartnerDAO' available:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=PartnerDao)}
```

As I mentioned, I'm new to Spring, and have been using Spring Boot's annotations to maneuver, but my supervisor constructed this `beans.xml` in order to integrate with other services and I'm not sure how to autowire it.

I can always do:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
PartnerDAO partnerDao = context.getBean(partner.dao.PartnerDAOImpl.class);
```

But I'd rather just autowire it.

Is there any other viable solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Add `@ImportResource` to your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class and pass it the name of your file to load (probably `classpath:applicationContext.xml`) to have it load the xml as well.

Answer (score 0):

Bean wiring corresponds to providing the dependencies a bean might need to complete it’s job. In Spring, beans can be wired together in two ways : Manually and Autowiring.

Manual wiring : using ref attribute in **property** or **constructor** tag

```
<bean id="PartnerDao" name="PartnerDao" class="partner.dao.PartnerDAOImpl">
   <constructor-arg index="0" value="${integration.username}">
<ref bean="PartnerDao" />
<constructor-arg/>
   <constructor-arg index="1" value="${integration.password}"/>
</bean>
```

I am not sure whether this will work or not but atleast you can try.

Comment: Can't I autowire a bean that was declared in an xml?